# If statement has to check if the id is already used if yes add to it, if no make it. Makes multiple times same id

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I am trying to make an array with forms linked to street names. To make sure the form is only once added to the array I loop thru it. Based on form id I either add id, name, percentage, and streets to the array $projectForms or only add the street if the id already exists in $projectForms.

The code:

```
$projectForms = [
        'projectName' => $projectName,
        'forms' => []
    ];

    foreach ($houses as $house) {
        foreach ($house['forms'] as $form) {

            if (!$projectForms['forms']) {
                array_push($projectForms['forms'], array('id' => $form['id'], 'name' => $form['name'], 'percentage' => $form['percentage'], 'streets' => array($house['fullStreet'])));
            } else {
                foreach ($projectForms['forms'] as $key => $value) {
                    if ($projectForms['forms'][$key]['id'] === $form['id']) {
                        array_push($projectForms['forms'][$key]['streets'], $house['fullStreet']);
                    } else if ($projectForms['forms'][$key]['id'] !== $form['id']) {
                        array_push($projectForms['forms'], array('id' => $form['id'], 'name' => $form['name'], 'percentage' => $form['percentage'], 'streets' => array($house['fullStreet'])));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dd($projectForms['forms']);
    //Return to the view
    dd($projectForms);
    return view('example')->with(['projectForms' => $projectForms]);
```

dd $houses:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97641
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 1"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97642
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 2"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97643
     "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 3"
     "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97644
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 4"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
   4 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97645
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 5"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2489
        "name" => "Some name"
        "percentage" => 3.3333333333333
      ]
    ]
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97646
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 6"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2489
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 3.3333333333333
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

dd $projectForms when done:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 2456
    "name" => "Some Name"
    "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
    "streets" => array:4 [▼
      0 => "Some Street 1"
      1 => "Some Street 2"
      2 => "Some Street 3"
      3 => "Some Street 4"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 2489
    "name" => "Some Name"
    "percentage" => 3.3333333333333
    "streets" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Some Street 5"
      1 => "Some Street 6"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 2489
    "name" => "Some Name"
    "percentage" => 3.3333333333333
    "streets" => array:1 [▼
       0 => "Some Street 6"
    ]
  ]
]
```

So as you can see in the dd from $projectForms Some Street 6 is added twice even though the id is used before. I am wondering what I can do to make my code only add it once.

Comment: Your logic in the innermost foreach loop appears to make rather little sense. You loop over _all_ already existing entries, and in _each iteration_ you make an array_push, in either the if- or the else-branch - so you are inserting as many new elements here as were already in `$projectForms['forms']` at that time, in a place where you should only be inserting a single one.

Comment: @04FS I see that now. Would that explain why the Some Street 6 is added last?

Comment: Yes. By the time you are processing that very last data item, your result array contains two entries already, for id 2456 and 2489. You are looping over both of them. In the first iteration, the id of what you want to add (2489) is not the same as the id you are currently looping over, 2456 - so street 6 gets added as a new element to your output array. In the next iteration, the ids do match - so you are adding street 6 to that second element now.

Comment: @04FS ooooohhhhhh. Thank you very much. If you can add an answer I can accept so you get rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic in the innermost foreach loop is off. You loop over *all* already existing entries, and in each iteration you make an array_push, in either the if- or the else-branch - so you are inserting as many new elements here as were already in $projectForms['forms'] at that time, in a place where you should only be inserting a single one.

> Would that explain why the Some Street 6 is added last?

Yes. By the time you are processing that very last data item, your result array contains two entries already, for id 2456 and 2489. You are looping over both of them. In the first iteration, the id of what you want to add (2489) is not the same as the id you are currently looping over, 2456 - so street 6 gets added as a new element to your output array. In the next iteration, the ids do match - so you are adding street 6 to that second element now.

---

Inside your inner loop, you need to add the current item to the existing element with the matching id, *if* you find such an item. If so, you can break out of the loop at that point, and there is nothing more to do. If not, you need to add the item as a new element *after* your loop. Use a flag to determine if that still needs to happen. Pseudocode:

```
$id_found = false;
foreach(loop over already existing elements in result array) {
  if( ids match ) {
    $id_found = true;
    // add item to existing element
    // ...
    break;
  }
}
if( !$id_found ) {
  // add item as new element
}
```